# Pure error message edit - how to react

Tags: discussion, edits, code-formatting

I had yesterday somebody, who simply dumped his unformatted error message into the text body. When I tried to edit it, to make it at least comprehensible, SO didn't allow me to do this. I understand the reason for the SO feedback "Please add some information to your code", but the error message was still incomprehensible. What is the suggested response in this case?

1. Ask the user to format and clarify - s/he didn't respond
2. Write additional text into the text body - I feel uncomfortable to do this with other people's posts, especially without understanding the intention of the post
3. Flag the question for moderator attention - isn't that a bit over the top?

Comment: Downvote, flag as "unclear what you are asking" and leave a comment asking for clarification. Nothing more you can do really.

Comment: And maybe hope someone with 2k+ comes along. Don't flag for moderator attention for code editing.

Comment: @Pekka & George: OK, I see, it is a problem of my low reputation points. I thought I was missing something. Very unsatisfactory, nonetheless, that every OP can dump unformatted code or error messages, but the system prevents us from formatting it. Thanks for the reply.

Comment: does formatting make it really better? That's what we call 'polishing a turd'. Downvote and flag, like Pekka 웃 said.

Comment: @Piinthesky I think this type of post isn't even worth your time to format it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The appropriate response to is to **downvote** and **flag** as "unclear what you are asking". You can also leave a comment asking for clarification.

Such a low-quality non-question isn't worth the time you would spend editing and formatting it. The expression 'polishing a turd' comes to mind.

<sub>Content assembled from comments by [Pekka웃](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360094/pure-error-message-edit-how-to-react?cb=1#comment536456_360094), [the_lotus](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360094/pure-error-message-edit-how-to-react?cb=1#comment536516_360094), and [jps](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360094/pure-error-message-edit-how-to-react?cb=1#comment536514_360094).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

I think I have misunderstood the question. I thought OP was asking about an otherwise well-written question which included badly formatted error message, for which the following answers. If the question itself was nothing more than a badly formatted error message (e.g. "I am getting this error ... pls help") then absolutely burn it with fire and [follow the advice in this answer instead](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/360183/4143855).

---

This comes up time and time again where lower-rep users who do not have sufficient privileges cannot perform an action they feel is best.

In this situation, you did the right thing. You tried to edit the post, but your edit wasn't accepted by the system as it was too insufficient. If there is truly NOTHING further to edit, then cancel the  edit, and leave a comment on the post. The comment will let the author know there is a formatting problem, but it also lets other community members know, and someone else may fix it up for you.

1. Yes, leave a comment by all means.
2. If there's nothing further to improve in the post, I agree with you to not edit it. <sup>1</sup>
3. Do NOT flag for moderation attention. This is simply one of those things where unfortunately you cannot make a change that would be better for the community.

Hope that your comment is actioned by either the OP or another community member. You are free to downvote the question if you feel the badly formatted error takes away from the question.

<sup>1</sup> That said, for an error message, you could probably easily add "This is the error I'm getting", or if something similar was added, you could modify it to "Here's the error".

Comment: Sorry, but I disagree. Adding "This is the error I'm getting" is no improvement at all and just a waste of time. It doesn't make the (non-)question clearer.